# McNemar test for three groups

Tags: correlation, bootstrap, proportion, mcnemar-test

I'm trying to examine the difference in proportions of outcomes from three different tests (positive, negative, unsure). I want to **compare what proportions of outcomes is positive for each test**. All three tests are performed on the same group of 100 subjects (so each subject underwent three different tests). I figured a McNemar test is most suitable as the results are correlated (because the same subjects were tested), cathegorical and I want to examine the proportions.
Each test yields a completely different range of outcomes so the categories 'positive', 'negative' and 'unsure'are assigned differently for each test. This makes me think i can't use a Cochran Q-test, but I correct me if i'm wrong.

My question is how to do a McNemar test for three treatments in R. I've been looking far and wide on the internet but can't seem to find an answer. [This article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2902578/pdf/nihms187308.pdf) suggests bootstrapping to compensate for the correlation but i thought that was already accounted for in a McNemar test.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your main goal: "I want to compare what proportions of outcomes is positive for each test". Could you try to specify the null and alternative hypothesis behind your question?

Comment: My null hypothesis is that all the tests yield the same proportion of positive subjects, the alternative is that they don't.